# How to use flatMapConcat?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am trying to use `flatMapConcat` as the following:

```
Source.empty
      .flatMapConcat {
        Source.fromFuture(Future("hello"))
      }
      .runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
      .onComplete {
        case Success(_) =>
          println()
        case Failure(e) =>
          println(s"Thrown ${e.getMessage}")
      }
```

and the compiler complains:

```
Error:(31, 26) type mismatch;
 found   : akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[String,akka.NotUsed]
 required: ? => akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[?],?]
        Source.fromFuture(Future("hello"))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method [flatMapConcat](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.22/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#flatMapConcat[T,M](f:Out=%3Eakka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[T],M]):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]) has the following signature:

```
def flatMapConcat[T, M](f: (Out) => Graph[SourceShape[T], M]): Repr[T]
```

which, in the case of processing a `Source` of `String`s, would expect a function like:

```
f: String => Source(Iterable[String])
```

Another issue with your sample code is that `Source.empty[T]` has no elements to be processed hence the subsequent `flatMapConcat` will never be executed.

Here's an example of using `flatMapConcat` to transform each element from a `Source` of names:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

Source(List("alice", "bob", "jenn")).
  flatMapConcat{ name => Source(List(s"Hi $name", s"Bye $name")) }.
  runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
// Hi alice
// Bye alice
// Hi bob
// Bye bob
// Hi jenn
// Bye jenn
```

As a side note, one could replace `flatMapConcat` in the above example with [mapConcat](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.22/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#mapConcat[T](f:Out=%3Escala.collection.immutable.Iterable[T]):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]) which expects a simpler function signature:

```
Source(List("alice", "bob", "jenn")).
  mapConcat{ name => List(s"Hi $name", s"Bye $name") }.
  runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
```